# change from command line a network adapter/interface used for Internet access on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, interface, connection

The general situation: I have Windows 7 64-bit professional, network connection via ethernet and plugged USB GSM modem. The problem is that sometimes my Internet provider has some outage and during such time I'd like to automatically use USB modem. I've already written some Perl code that actively tests if connection is down and can run a shell command to switch the adapter used for Internet access.

The question is how to change the adapters from command prompt. I'd prefer not giving the script administrative privileges but if it's unavoidable, I can bear this.

Preliminary look-around:

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic nic get name, index
Index  Name
0      WAN Miniport (SSTP)
1      WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
2      WAN Miniport (L2TP)
3      WAN Miniport (PPTP)
4      WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
5      WAN Miniport (IPv6)
6      WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
7      Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
8      WAN Miniport (IP)
9      Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
10     RAS Async Adapter
11     Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
12     Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
13     Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
```

"netstat -rn" shows that adapter for Local Area Connection has higher priority for binding than the modem, which is good.

The usage of my USB modem for casual user consists of running a bespoke application for it and clicking a button "Connect/Disconnect". AFAIK the app doesn't have command line options.

In one direction I figured out a workaround that has additional advantage of keeping the connection alive: AutoConnect 0.1.3.1 by Jarek "Shider" Wieczorek. AFAIK it has no command line options, but just running it after it has been once configured establishes GSM connection and later reconnects in case, which is great.

Now I stuck on how to switch back to LAN (which is my primary, quicker access to the net) after some time, when Internet access has been restored. After killing AutoConnect, the connection is still via modem. I suspected that switching back could be some netsh command but haven't found anything obvious in the help. In a desperate attempt I thought of disabling the modem using devcon.exe but the program downloaded from
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=311272
didn't run (some errors that I won't cite because they're actually unrelated to the main issue) and before downloading huge Windows Driver Kit 7.1.0 for a hopefully better version I thought I'll ask here for some suggestion/solution :)

Thank you in advance for any neat general solution or a small specific solution on how to turn off USB connection (maybe Windows will automatically use LAN then) or switch to LAN.

EDIT:
Belatedly, I came up with a solution. Supposing a modem connection has the name ABCD, the following terminates it after closing AutoConnect:

```
rasdial ABCD /disconnect
```

However, I still think the whole idea I presented is quite awkward and would gladly see some neat approach. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to increase the *metric* (lower the priority) for the ethernet's gateway to `255.255.255.255` via `route change`.